# StaticResource not found in WPF project

Tags: wpf, xaml

So I have my template defined in the Window.Resources

```
<Window.Resources>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="tree:TreeNode" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}" x:Key="template">
       <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayName}"/>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

And I referenced it in the TreeView like this

```
<TreeView Name="DirTreeView" BorderBrush="White" ItemsSource="{Binding FileSystemTreeNodes}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource template}"/>
```

But when I try to start my application it throws an exception. The exception message says that it could not find the resource with the name "template". Why is that?

Comment: this is weird, have you tried restarting vs or rebuilding the solution?

Comment: @Bizz yes I restarted and rebuilded several times but it still doesn't work

Comment: Remove the DataType from the HierarchicalDataTemplate declaration.

Comment: @Clemens That worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `DataType` property of a DataTemplate implicitly sets an `x:Key`.

You typically do not need both, so either remove the DataType or put if after the key:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="template" DataType="tree:TreeNode" ...>
```